# Sigfox parse error: Why can it not send my message?

Tags: arduino, message, parse-error

I'm testing the Sigfox communication with a [Breakout board BRKWS01](https://partners.sigfox.com/products/sigfox-breakout-board-brkws01) and a Nucleo-32 L432KC. I work with Arduino IDE. I can send a message of 12 bytes. I used 12 "char" to save my data but it did not work. Then I test with 3 "int" but I always receive the error message: "Error: parse error", and I don't know why.

This is the structure of my message:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned int temperature;
  unsigned int latitude;
  unsigned int longitude;
} Payload;
```

Here is my code:

```
#include "IO_WSSFM10.h"

IO_WSSFM10 mySigfox(10, 11, true);

typedef struct {
  unsigned int temperature;
  unsigned int latitude;
  unsigned int longitude;
} Payload;

unsigned int counter=0;

void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  mySigfox.begin();
  delay(50);
  mySigfox.test();
  mySigfox.getID();
  mySigfox.getPAC();
  mySigfox.getTemp();

  //mySigfox.setPowerMode(1);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {  
  String sfResponse;
  Payload p;
  p.temperature = 1075847679;
  p.latitude = 441300000;
  p.longitude = 41000000;

  bool statusS = mySigfox.send(&p, sizeof(p));
  if (statusS) counter++;

  delay(10000);
  /*
  bool statusSR = mySigfox.sendReceive(&p, sizeof(p), sfResponse);
  if (statusS) {
    for (uint8_t i= 0; i<26; ++i) {//RX= 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
      Serial.println(sfResponse[i]);
      counter++;
    }
  }*/
}
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: You've left out very important parts of the sketch. Where does mySigfox come from? What kind of data does mySigfox.send() expect?

Comment: At which line do you get the parser error?

Comment: If you enable debug output, what output do you get?

Comment: It doesn't explain where is the error. I just get the message: Data: ERROR: perse error

Comment: The debug prints before the error will show how far into the code the processor got.

Comment: The error comes from the Sigfox module: it checks if messages are successfully sent.